# Visual Studio 2012 view fired events

Tags: winforms, events, visual-studio-2012

In `Visual Studio 2012`, How can I view all of the fired events during debugging?

For example, moving from one control to another [fires five events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx). I would like to view all of them while debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only thing you can do is write code for them all.

There isn't an easy way to do this because the application isn't thinking in terms of "moving from one control to another". Instead, the user activates one control (which causes some events) which has a (possible) side effect of deactivating another control (which causes some events).

Events are raised because some individual object has something to say - they aren't raised because of a higher-level idea like moving from one control to another. It's the fact that each object is responsible for raising its own events that makes it problematic to just see all the events that happen.

There might be a developer tool that can observe your form, add event handlers for every event of the form and every control on it, and show you the events as they're fired, but I think you're going to be in for quite a lot of information at that point.